# typescript errors with react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to use react-router but I get the following errors related to typescript. I have the following dependencies @types/react-router 5.1.3, @types/react-router-dom 5.1.3, typescript 3.7.3

> [ts] JSX element type 'BrowserRouter' is not a constructor function
> for JSX elements.   Property 'render' is missing in type
> 'BrowserRouter'.
>
> [ts] JSX element class does not support attributes
> because it does not have a 'props' property.

Here is a snippet of my code where I am trying to use the Router. The syntax follows the same convention as many of the examples I've found online, so I'm sure that's not the problem. Can't find any other posts about this issue and I'm not very familiar with the underbelly of typescript so I'm not sure what to start messing with to fix this error. Thanks.

```js
export default (props : IProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const Home = () => {
    return (<div className={classes.app}>
      <Header />
    </div>);
  };

  const Edit = () => {
    return (<div className={classes.app}>
      <Header />
    </div>);
  }

  return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/edit" component={Edit}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: I can't pin point why this is happening as I haven't used react-router in a while. But I've run into similar problems when the versions of modules and their type definitions don't match. Start by taking a look at the `package.json` and the `lock file`. As an extreme step you could always try deleting `lock file` and `node_modules` and reinstalling

Comment: Deleting node_modules and running npm install again cleared things up. Thanks